# Маршрутизация Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Допустим есть маршруты:

```
Route::get('category/{id}/{action}')
```

Получается, что ссылки в виде

```
/category/1/show

/category/1/edit

/category/1/remove
```

Подходят под наш маршрут. Это все хорошо, но **нужно чтобы они выполнялись в разных методах**. И вот это уже не получается. 
Пробовал таким способом:

```
Route::get('category/{id}/{action}', "Controller@show")->where("action"=>"show")

Route::get('category/{id}/{action}', "Controller@edit")->where("action"=>"edit")

Route::get('category/{id}/{action}', "Controller@remove")->where("action"=>"remove")
```

Но при такой схеме, всегда выполняется последний маршрут.

Прошу вариант с парсом URL не предлагать. Хочу понять возможно ли это делать средствами laravel

Comment: А стандартный `Route::resource('category', 'Controller')` не подходит для этих целей?

Comment: Также вы пишите **нужно чтобы они выполнялись в разных контроллерах**, но в примере кода у вас один контроллер и разные методы.

Comment: @РустамГимранов простите, Вы правы, в разных методах должны выполнятся.

Comment: Тогда не вижу подвоха в вопросе ) Но если вы знаете что `"action"=>"show"`, то почему не Route::get('category/{id}/show', "Controller@show")? А вообще правильнее `Route::resource('category', 'Controller')`

Comment: @РустамГимранов мне нужно данный `{action}` использовать в посреднике, чтобы не писать один и тот же код в матодах контроллера

Comment: Вот, как чуял, что-то не так ) Хотите при помощи посредника разграничивать права пользователей на доступ к определённому разделу?

Comment: @РустамГимранов ну это один из моментов)

Comment: В посреднике доступно `$request->segment(3)`, а роуты лучше через *Route::resource*

Comment: @РустамГимранов спасибо, будем разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Советую впервую очередь ознакомиться с документацией. Чтобы не плодить подобные действия достаточно создать ресурсный контроллер и в маршуте указать такой же тип - resourse.

Более подробно можно почитать здесь:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score -1):

Можно прописать разные методы в одном контроллере и в зависимости от action выполнять эти методы. К примеру в web.php оставляете только одну строку

```
Route::get('category/{id}/{action}', "Controller@router");
```

В контроллере делаете так

```
public function router($id, $action) {
    if ($action == 'show') {
        $this->show($id);
    }
}
public function show($id) {
    //ваш код
}
public function edit($id) {
    //ваш код
}
public function remove($id) {
    //ваш код
}
```